# Can I convert a patch for linux kernel into a Loadable Kernel Module?

Tags: module, linux-kernel, patch

I have a patch for vanila linux kernel which includes new files as well as changes in original Kernel SourceTree files too.

I want to make this patch a Loadable Kernel Module so that I can avoid any rebuild of basic kernel.

As this patch has changes in header files as well as .c and data file of org kernel source, I have a doubt whether this can be made a Kernel Module?

Please ask for any more details you want to clarify the issue.

Thanks,
Sapan

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no.

A more nuanced answer: Yes, it's *theoretically* possible to do something like what you're envisioning. However, it's enormously complex -- every detail has got to be exactly right -- and not something you could hope to do in an ad-hoc manner. For example, every data structure that increases in size might cause huge areas of memory to need to be reallocated and relocated, and every pointer pointing to one of those pieces of data would then need to be adjusted, and there is a potential cascade of further dependent adjustments. There's simply no way to track all those details.

But see https://www.ksplice.com/, which actually patches a kernel at runtime. I don't know many details about ksplice, but I'm fairly certain it's only possible to do this with very tight constraints on what exactly changes due to the concerns I outlined above, among others.

Comment: You should have stopped after the first sentence, i.e. the OP cannot *"avoid any rebuild of basic kernel"* with a patch to *source* code..

Comment: Actually I also had the thought once looking at the fact that, the patch that needs to be made KLM has changes in Kernel source tree, but still just want to confirm. One more thing I would like to share is, the patch has introduced a new structure and initialized it under init_task.h. And as far as I know, init_task.h helps to create initial task table of 2MB around. We cannot change it by a KLM during runtime. Please correct me if I am wrong. And thanks for your   response.